# Where to put a text file in JSP Project with NetBeans

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans-8

I'm accessing a method of class(which is not servlet) from servlet.

I'm reading a properties file inside this m1.

```
Properties props=null
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("Interface.properties");
props.load(input);
```

But it is showing IOException. I don't want to give relative path.
Where should i put this file to run it smoothly.

Right now I've put the file @

> /home/sys6002/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/Interface.properties

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file in your classpath and you can load it like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Interface.properties"));
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?. Thanks

Comment: you can put the file under the source folder, where you have *.java files. Anywhere in any package.